# Does a 3rd party spamming with links to a website get that website blacklisted?

Tags: email, spam, spam-prevention, blacklist

Paul has a website he is a nice person he never wants to get banned or blacklisted.

Jason is a bad and malicious person, he send 200K real emails in 1 hour, with the Paul's website link inside the email body.

Does this affects Paul or Paul's website in anyway?

If answer is yes, how can Paul prevent any of those situations?

Comment: @Stephen Ostemiller yeah sorry and thanks for the edit i'm really not good on english :P

Comment: SPF and DKIM can be set up such that everyone knows where mail from your domain is supposed to originate. Beyond that, the filters don't usually care about the contents of the email, just the servers that are sending the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul cannot stop Jason from sending emails with Pauls link. The websites within the email shouldn't be blacklisted, though the IP and or Domain of the mail server may get blacklisted by email filters if enough complaints are sent in to hosting providers. Depending on Jason is sending his emails, spam and junk mail filters may already be doing their job and not allowing these emails to reach recipient inbox's. If Paul knows with absolute certainty that Jason is sending these emails there are ways to stop him, especially if the emails are slanderous.